# C# Image and label issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue when I'm trying to make my image or label visible in my web app.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.Adapters;


public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("c:/test.pdf"))
            //inform user
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded.");
        Image1.visible = true;
```

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
The name 'Image1' does not exist in the current context
```

Any ideas here? Ive done this before without issue, but for some reason it doesn't like the `image1` (which i put on my webpage and made `visible = false`) nor the label which is also `visible = false`.

Comment: please, try to format the code

Comment: How and where is `Image1` declared? Have you spelled the name correctly?

Comment: @Albin -  protected void Image1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

Comment: That's a method, not a field or property.  How is your Image1 control declared in markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Image1 is declared "protected", also make sure that Image1 is the id="" for the runat="sever" control on the page.

If neither of these work, try making a trivial change to the markup to recompile the whole page class.

Comment: When I put this in:  protected void Image1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } It then gives me an error saying its a method which is not valid given the context.

Comment: protected System.Web.UI.Controls.WebControls.Image Image1;

Answer (score 0):

had issues similar to this before, usually caused by the designer not updating after adding new control to the page. to fix i would recommend

1. taking the image control with id of image1 out of the page.
2. then save the page.
3. now close the aspx page.
4. re open the aspx again
5. place image control with id image1 back onto the page again and save.

think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the designer.cs file for the page and then re-open the aspx page in Design mode. Next do a full rebuild of the project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that timer_tick it's not in the same thread of your web app